# Dropbox Python API - Team Folder Access

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I am trying to connect to Dropbox to read in a csv into my python program. I can currently connect, but I can't access the folder I want to access. I configured my app to have all access. When I click on "All Files" in Dropbox Desktop, I currently have two folder there- We'll call them Folder 1 and Folder 2. I want to access a file within Folder 2, which is a Team folder. We do not have Team Space as far as I can tell but I could be wrong ,if that's applicable.

My code looks like this:

```
try:
    dropbox_file_path = ''

    # connect to dropbox using member id
    dbx = dropbox.DropboxTeam(os.getenv('DROPBOX_TOKEN')).as_user(member_id)

    # list all the files from the folder
    result = dbx.files_list_folder(dropbox_file_path, recursive=False)

    #  print entries
    for entry in result.entries:
        print(entry.name)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This code works just fine, but it only prints out the file/folder names within Folder 1. As you can see, my path is an empty string, which should point it to my root. Is there a reason I can't see or access the other folder? I have admin access to Folder 2. It behaves as though that folder doesn't exist and Folder 1 is my root folder. I thought the "All Files" link in dropbox would take me to my root, which would mean Folder 1 and Folder 2 would be children of it, but it doesn't seem to think so. How can I access the correct files?

I get a LookupError when I try to access the file I want since it can't get into that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like your team does use the team space configuration.

By default, API calls operate in the "member folder" of the connected account, not the "[team space](https://help.dropbox.com/organize/team-space-overview)". You can configure API calls to operate in the "team space" instead though. To do so, you'll need to set the "Dropbox-API-Path-Root" header. You can find information on this in [the Team Files Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/dbx-team-files-guide).

In that case, you would do something like:

```py
root_namespace_id = dbx.users_get_current_account().root_info.root_namespace_id
dbx = dbx.with_path_root(dropbox.common.PathRoot.root(root_namespace_id))

def handle_entries(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry)

folder_path = ""

res = dbx.files_list_folder(path=folder_path, recursive=False)
handle_entries(res.entries)
while res.has_more:
    res = dbx.files_list_folder_continue(cursor=res.cursor)
    handle_entries(res.entries)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! This is the only thing that has worked for me after hours and hours on the internet.